# div with image on left and title and text on right

Tags: html, image, text, bootstrap-4

I need to create `div` exactly same as on picture. Left side should be populated with `image` and right with title and description bellow. Take into account that it is something like left side is `col-5` and right side is `col-7` or similar, and image no matter what the original size is, it should fit inside, and description can be very long. So `div` should be expandable vertically. Also is it possible to implement `"read more"` button and show only first `300 chars` if description is long, and on button click, expand the rest?

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively simple to achieve using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.section {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.paragraph {
  color: #555;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  padding: 20px;
}

.title {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #222;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" class="image" />
  <div class="content">

    <h2 class="title">
      This is a title
    </h2>
    <p class="paragraph">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At non ex earum, libero dignissimos voluptates. Quis beatae dolorem autem ipsa!
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```